# Entity Framework - get related items without explicit reference using Fluent API configurations

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework-6, fluent

Let's say I have database table A with optional property X.
I have table B with a composite key (Y, X). These two tables are not explicitly related in any way.

e.g.

```
create table A
(
    Id uniqueidentifier not null,
    X uniqueidentifier null
)

create table B
(
    Y uniqueidentifier not null,
    X uniqueidentifier not null,
    Constraint PK_B Primary Key (Y, X)
)
```

A and B are implicitly related via property X, in the sense that X is an orphan id (its base table has been moved out)

For my model A in C# code, how can I populate `IList<B>` using property X to get all items in B containing X? Ideally, I'd like to use Fluent API configurations.

e.g

```
public class A {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid? X {get; set;}
    public IList<B> RelatedItems {get; set;}
}

public class B {
    public Guid X {get; set;}
    public Guid Y {get; set;}
}
```

How do I configure my entities using Fluent API so that I can use something like

```
var list = await context.AQuery()
.Include(a => a.RelatedItems)
.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

or any other way to populate IList in A

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi have you tried something already? That we we can see where you are and if you actually already have the table with composite key. If you haven't than you should make that your main goal first.

Comment: Since `X` is not the PK of A, you can't let EF6 relate B to A. Hence the only options is to use LINQ queries with manual joins.

Comment: @Stefan - This is exactly what we have. The reason is, both the tables were having Foreign Key X referring to a table which we decided to remove on some performance concerns. But we still need to get the related records as I described. Previously it was easy via this removed table!!

Comment: @IvanStoev - The manual way requires some back and forth between separate databases because of our removed (related) table in a separate database as I mentioned earlier. I was kind of trying to avoid that if there is some magic configuration!

Comment: Your database doesn't know about the relationship, so an abstraction (ORM) on that is unlikely to know either. Instead, a view might fit the bill, and you can use EF to query the view. Even an indexed view (if your dbms supports it) might work if it's static enough, and that can help with performance.

Comment: If you have the classes and `DbSet`s you better show them. Also, if you'd show some first efforts we'd see where you're stuck. It's not really clear what you expect us to answer.

Comment: @GertArnold, please see the edited question. I hope it conveys my intentions now. Thanks

Comment: Well, I think [previous comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919541/entity-framework-get-related-items-without-explicit-reference-using-fluent-api?noredirect=1#comment90789051_51919541) made clear you can't do this. *Unless* you tell EF that `X` is `A`'s primary key, but then `X` should be unique for each `A`

Comment: @GertArnold, IvanStoev Looks like there is only manual (LINQ) way left for me. Thanks all. Will update/share if I find something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

in ur model a x is a property , a property has a getter , u can set the get method of the x property to retrieve the records from the database  (similar to the lazy loading design pattern )

```
public IList<SomeStuff> X {
get { // go get records from database }
}
```

this will cost u an extra so i am not sure if this is what u want